# How to update custom Javafx with data in the most effiecient way

Tags: java, javafx

I have a working system where one Custom component can be updated by user clicking button or by timer. But I'm not sure this is the most efficient way and if it is thread safe.

Is there any better way to solve this?

I have component based on Canvas: MyBox
One class that holds the data: MyColorBox
Listening interface: MyColorBoxListener

From the main class:

```
pane.getChildren().add( new MyBox( myboxdata));
```

The data can be updated by timers or user clicking by calling:

```
myboxdata.update();
```

The user can choice Play, Stop or Next. Play and Stop will control the timer. If the timer is stoppe it will be possible to click Next.

My data class:

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class MyColorBox {
    Color color[] = new Color[]{Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN};
    Color color_second;
    int counter = 0;

    MyColorBoxListener listener;

    public MyColorBox(MyColorBoxListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public MyColorBox() {
        setListener(null);
    }

    public void setListener(MyColorBoxListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void update() {
        if(++counter>=color.length) counter=0;
        if(listener!=null)
            listener.updated();
    }

    public Color getCurrentColor() {
        return color[counter];
    }
}
```

Listener interface:

```
public interface BouncingBoxListener {
    public void updated();
}
```

My Component:

```
    public class MyBox extends Canvas implements MyColorBoxListener {
        MyColorBox box;

        public MyBox( MyColorBox box) {
            super(100,100);
            this.box = box;

            box.setListener(this);

            draw();
        }

        public void draw() {
            GraphicsContext gc = this.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.setStroke( box.getCurrentColor());
            gc.setLineWidth(2);
            gc.strokeRect(0,0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        }
    @Override
    public void updated() {
        draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the end user updating the data? Data change, input from a `TextField` somewhere else needs to be accounted for, etc.. Just trying to get a fuller picture.

Comment: @HypnicJerk it can be updated by timer or user. I edited the description.

Comment: have to admit that I still don't understand your requirement and where you suspect any problem (or did you measure performance/responsiveness?) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @kleopatra I do have a working solution but I'm unsure if this is the best way of connecting javafx components with data. I have not yet measured performance.